# How to automate the process of converting the list of .dat files, with their dictionaries (in seperate .dct format), to pandas data frames?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

The following code coverts .dat files into data frames with the use of its dictionary file in .dct format. It works well. But my problem is that I was unable to automate this process, creating a loop that takes the pairs of these files from lists is a little bit tricky, atleast for me. I could really use some help with that.

```
try:
    from statadict import parse_stata_dict
except ImportError:
    !pip install statadict

import pandas as pd
from statadict import parse_stata_dict
```

```
dict_file = '2015_2017_FemPregSetup.dct'
data_file = '2015_2017_FemPregData.dat'
```

```
stata_dict = parse_stata_dict(dict_file)
stata_dict

nsfg = pd.read_fwf(data_file, 
                   names=stata_dict.names, 
                   colspecs=stata_dict.colspecs)
# nsfg is now a pandas DataFrame
```

These are the lists of files that I would like to convert into data frames. Every .dat file has its own dictionary file:

```
dat_name = ['2002FemResp.dat',
'2002Male.dat'...

dct_name = ['2002FemResp.dct',
'2002Male.dct'...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both lists have the same length and you will want to save the csv dataframe you could try:

```
c=0
for dat,dct in zip(dat_name, dct_name):
    c+=1
    stata_dict = parse_stata_dict(dct)
    pd.read_fwf(dat, names=stata_dict.names, colspecs=stata_dict.colspecs).to_csv(r'path_name\file_name_{}.csv'.format(c))
    # don't forget the '.csv'!
```

Also consider that if you are not using windows you need to use '/' rather than '\'  in your path (or you can use [os.path.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) to avoid this issue.

Comment: Thank you, thats very helpful! Although, this code saves all files into one .csv file. I would prefer to keep them separate. I know how to handle a list of dataframes and make them into seperate .csv files. So, I would like to have as an output a list of data frames. I tried simply: 

'''
pd.read_fwf[dat, names=stata_dict.names, colspecs=stata_dict.colspecs]
'''
But I end up with only one data frame in a list

Comment: I edited the asnwer, you can use a variable and str.format() to create different csv files